# Create object from dll then calling a method

Tags: dll, vbscript, batch-file, activex, dllimport

I am trying to call some methods from a dll library. I have found some examples in JavaScript and c++ . I don't know how to use c++ so let me show you what I have worked out for the JavaScript example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Palm Pad</title>
</HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2">

if(window.ActiveXObject) {

    //var ActiveHomeObj = new ActiveXObject("X10.ActiveHome");

} else {

    alert("This script was design to work with Internet Explore 5 and up");

}


function getUSCode(Button1,OnOff)
{
    ActiveHomeObj.SendAction("sendplc","A1 on");
}
</script>

<body>


<a href="javascript:getUSCode(1,'on');">click here to see if method runs</a>

<OBJECT ID="ActiveHomeObj" classid="CLSID:001000AF-2DEF-0208-10B6-DC5BA692C858" codebase="ahscript.dll"  type="application/x-oleobject"></OBJECT>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see this is a very simple html page with just one JavaScript function that gets executed when clicking on the link. The problem with this script is that it only works with internet explorer and when using it I get the [image]  warning.

If I use internet explorer and I enable the blocked content I am able to execute the SendAction method on the ahscript.dll library.

I will like to run this with other browsers as well so it will be nice if I can create a .bat file that would enable me to do the same thing. Or a vbs script. Or any other script...

if for some reason you know AutoIt here is what I have tried out with it:

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/):

```
DllCall("ahscript.dll","none","SendAction","str","sendplc","str", "A1 on") 

and

$o = ObjCreate("C:\Users\Virgilio\Desktop\x10\ahscript.dll")
$o.SendAction("sendplc","A1 on")
```

in vbs I have treid something similar.

How could I create an executable file that when executing it I can get the same result that if I where to open the html file in internet explorer then enable the warning and lastly executing the javascrip function?

Comment: what problems did you find with your autoit and vbs attempts?

Comment: I guess I'll try the c++ library. Maybe I can create a wrapper with c#. I am most comfortable working with c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you're out of luck here.

First, [ActiveXObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is specific to Internet Explorer.  [Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/ActiveX) and [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#activex) do not support it.  You can use special plugins for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab/) and [Chrome](http://www.chromeextensions.org/utilities/ie-tab/) that will enable an IE tab, but that is still IE.

In addition, ActiveX/COM is specific to Windows.  You can use ActiveX/COM from [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), but it is not natively supported by any other OS.